# Relation between nonlinearity and hypothesis set in the view of bias variance trade off

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bias-variance-tradeoff, vc-dimension

I understand bias variance Trade off pretty well in terms of linear regression. As when the functions gets more wiggly (higher degrees) then variance on test set increases. Makes sense.

However, in a lecture that I've gone through recently, it is said that : as the hypothesis set gets huge, then there is chance for increase in variance from the true function.

I couldn't get the intuition behind that. What I understand is that here hypothesis set size is equated to the nonlinearity degree. Please explain the reason behind that statement.

Comment: My understanding is that as your hypothesis set increases in range, you are willing to accept a larger amount of values for the variables you are hypothesizing about. Since you are willing to accept more values, you are inherently allowing the function to have more variation.